# ¿Donde se deben crear los ficheros JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Estoy empezando a aprender sobre java web con tomcat y me está dando problemas donde colocar cada fichero. Los servlets y las clases de java, las estoy creando dentro de `src` pero los ficheros `jsp`,`html`, la vista de mi aplicación, donde debería ir dentro de mi proyecto?

Estuve viendo que se agregan dentro de la carpeta `WEB-INF` pero al no ser pública como puedo acceder a ella mediante `servlet's`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los JSPs y otros recursos de la vista deben ir de lado de los recursos web de la aplicación, esto es, la carpeta webapp, webview, web resources o como sea que esté denominada en tu proyecto. Todos los archivos que estén dentro de tus carpetas fuente (src o como lo configures) irán últimamente a la carpeta WEB-INF/classes, donde residen tus compilados.

Considera que si colocas un archivo JSP dentro de WEB-INF, entonces los usuarios de tu aplicación no pueden acceder a esa información mediante el enlace de JSP. Esto es útil cuando necesitas pre procesar la petición antes de mostrar la vista, clásico de una arquitectura MV* (MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc.).

Por ejemplo, si necesitas cargar una lista de productos de tu fuente de datos (base de datos, servicio web, etc) y mostrarla en la aplicación, se complica más al tener el JSP como acceso directo al cliente puesto que tendrías que colocar código Java en el JSP para obtener la información y luego mostrarla, esto se logra con scriptlets pero esa tecnología no debe utilizarse, no se recomienda. En cambio, al colocar tu archivo JSP dentro de WEB-INF facilitas este proceso al invocar primero el servlet y que este haga un forward a la vista apropiada.

Aquí un ejemplo breve. Se asume que tienes como dependencias en tu proyecto la librería JSTL.

Estructura del proyecto:

```
src
- edu.ltmj.controller
  + ArticulosServlet.java
Web Resources (o como se llame en tu proyecto)
- WEB-INF
  + articulos.jsp
  + web.xml
- resources
  + (tus archivos de recursos: JS, CSS, imágenes, etc, que son de acceso libre)
```

Código de `ArticulosServlet`:

```
public class ArticulosServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        ArticuloService articuloService = new ArticuloService();
        List<Articulo> listaArticulos = articuloService.getListaArticulos(); //se conecta a base de datos u otra fuente de datos para traer la lista de artículos
        req.setAttribute("listaArticulos", listaArticulos);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/articulos.jsp")
            .forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

Código de articulos.jsp:

```html
<%--
    Se agrega la librería JSTL
    Indispensable para realizar MV* con JSPs
--%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Articulos</title>
</head>
<body>
    Lista de artículos:
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${listaArticulos}" var="articulo">
            <tr>
                <td>${articulo.nombre}</td>
                <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${articulo.precio}" type="currency" maxFractionDigits="3" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se deben almacenar en el folder que se llama `WebContent`, aquí se agregan los recursos incluyendo los archivos .jsp, .html, imágenes etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para acceder de un servlet a el folder `WebContent` me imagino lo sabes, de cualquier forma lo agrego para otros usuarios, por ejemplo, de acuerdo a la imagen, si deseamos acceder al archivo .jsp dentro del folder `/jsp`:

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String pathWebContent = context.getRealPath("/");
String pathJsp = pathWebContent + "/jsp/Sample.jsp" ;
```

> Folder **WebContent**  Ubicación obligatoria de todos los recursos web,
>   incluyendo HTML, JSP, archivos gráficos, etc.

para más información :
[Proyectos web dinámicos y aplicaciones.](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwebprj.html)

Comment: *En WEB-INF no, ahi deben estar recursos de soporte, los folders /lib y clases, así como sus imágenes* **craso error**. Allí es donde pertenecen los JSPs, puesto que de esa manera solo se acceden mediante los controladores (servlets) que permiten pre procesar información como cargar información de una lista a mostrar al cliente. Un buen ejemplo de esto es Spring MVC donde en su tutorial te explican que los JSPs o la vista debe ir dentro de esta carpeta, no afuera.